# Stack Reputational: User rankings in detail

Tags: app, website, coffeescript

[image: Stack Reputational Screenshot]

### About

Let me present my app to you, **"Stack Reputational"** (available at http://sr.ericbae.com).

Stack Reputational is a Stack Overflow leaderboard unlike any other! It gives you the most detailed look at Stack Overflow users and their rankings. You can view users and their rankings based on their

- Country
- State
- City
- Age or age groups
- User's interests/topics

And then sort them by the reputation they gained

- Today
- This past week
- Past month
- Past quarter
- Past year

You can also click on each user to view even more information about that user. Very soon, I hope to add features to rank users by their interest topics and compare countries, states and cities to see which regions of the world are highly ranked in Stack Overflow community.

UPDATE: You can now rank the users based on different topics! Find out who has the highest rank in C++ aged between 20-30 living in UK! Now that's a detailed ranking.

### Platform

Sounds cool? Well head over to "http://sr.ericbae.com" for a test-drive. There's nothing to download and it's accessible via the web.

### Contact

Stack Reputational was created by me "Eric Bae". I blog sporadically at "ericbae.com", or you can follow me @eric_bae on Twitter for any more information.

### Code

Stack Reputational was built on

- PHP 5 on CodeIgniter with the REST framework
- MySQL database
- JavasScript ([CoffeeScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CoffeeScript), jQuery, [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), Handlebars for templating)
- CSS - 1140 pixels grid layout, LESS framework
- jQuery plugins - momentjs for dates & time, jquery.url for parsing URL segments
- Source code is available at https://github.com/ericbae/StackReputational

#### Update

29-02-2012

- Bug fix on correct user rankings when filtering through country
- A quick bug fix on pagination
- NEW - it now lets you rank users by the topics they are interested in!
- NEW - You can now download the entire source code for Stack Reputational on GitHub. https://github.com/ericbae/StackReputational

28-02-2012

- Bug fix on changing cities and states for displaying user rankings properly.

25-02-2012

- Bug fix on user rankings with unknown location and age group

24-02-2012

- Released to Stack Apps

Comment: I found a small bug, I searched for Germany->Brandenburg->Potsdam, viewed the results and then changed to Berlin. The City was changed to ALL in the view but was still Potsdam in the URL (thus no results found). When I selected Berlin (as City) everything was right.

Comment: Thanks @oers, I just committed the bug fix. I think it's ok now! thanks for pointing out again.

Comment: Looks interesting, is it still up?  Your site now redirects to your "else if" site.